# How to get the data from an excel file located in a Sharepoint to Tosca through the SchemaPath Excel DataSource?

Tags: automation, tosca

I am working on a project in Tosca Commander, one of the requirements is that the data Excel input file will be located in a Sharepoint and Tosca must access it and retrieve the data to run the automation. The contents of this file will change with every execution. 

I used a Template to configurate the automation and Tosca receives the input by using the Template Instantiation option. To use an Excel file as DataSource I need to provide the path to the file in the SchemaPath property. I currently have the Excel file locally on my computer, so providing the path to it is very simple.

The issue I'm having is with the Sharepoint part. I know I can link the Sharepoint folder in my computer's files so Tosca can easily access it. But this doesn't meet the project's requirements. I need Tosca to access the Sharepoint directly and retrieve the data from there, downloading the file from Sharepoint is not an option either.

Comment: so what is the problem? Cant you put the link to sharepoint in the Path field?

Comment: @Psytho No, Tosca throws an error saying the path is invalid

Comment: how does your sharepoint path look like?

Comment: @Psytho Something like this "https://sharepoint.com/.../.../..."

Comment: what about permissions? Do you need to authorize to access this file?